# How do i Increment every 12th time and Keeping a running total with an object literal and while loop?

Tags: javascript, loops, sum, increment

**A little history.** 
This was a homework problem I've turned in. They wanted me to increment the year in this code after 12 monthly payments and keep a running total on how much interest I paid. The code works or doesn't throw errors.

**The problem.** 
I don't know how to increment an object literal property every 12 iterations. (To show you've made twelve payments and the next year started) I couldn't figure how to keep a running total of the interest paid.

**Things I've tried.** 
I've tried using a loops with in the year property. Either it cant be done or I was doing something wrong. Ive tried increment the year based off of the payment ID with an if else, but it only increments once. Ive tried incrementing the year before and after the loop. Then it syncs up with the payment ID, partial success?

```
function displayWelcome() {
  printLine();
  console.log('Welcome to the credit card payoff tool.');
  printLine();
  console.log('This program will determine the time it \nwill take to pay off a credit card!');
  printLine();
}
displayWelcome();

function calculateMinimumPayment(balance, interestRate) {    
  var calcMinPay = balance * interestRate; 
  console.log(calcMinPay);  
  return calcMinPay 
}

function generatePaymentId() {  // lines 14 - 22 are a closure function. 
  var count = 0;
  function paymentId() {
    count ++;           
    return count;
  }
  return paymentId;
};
var id = generatePaymentId();



function processPaymentSchedule(balance, interest, minimumPayment) {
  var year = 1;
  var counter = 0;
  while (balance > 0) {
    counter ++;
    year += 0.08333333333;
    var interestDecimal = interest / 100;
    var interestMonthly = interestDecimal / 12;
    var interestPaid = balance * interestMonthly;
    var princplePaid = minimumPayment - interestPaid;
    var balance = balance - princplePaid;    

    var payment = {
      year: year.toFixed(0), 
      balance: balance.toFixed(2), 
      paymentId: id(), 
      interestPaid: interestPaid.toFixed(2)
    };

    function definePayment() {
      console.log(payment);  
    } 

    definePayment();

    if (payment.paymentId > 11) {
      year += 1;
    } 

  }
}

function printLine() {
  console.log('---------------------------------------');
}


processPaymentSchedule (1500, 18, 30);
```

**Errors:** No error messages in this code, just dont know how to do the things listed above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To figure out if it is a "every Nth" count on the iteration, you can use the modulo operator `%` to get the remainder from basic integer division.  Simply modulo your counter variable by 12 and if the counter is greater than 0 then it is on the 12th, 24th, etc. run through your loop.

```
  var counter = 0;
  while (balance > 0) {
    counter ++; 
    if (counter%12==0)
        console.log("You are on a (N*12)th loop run");  
    }
  }
```

However, when it comes to calculating interest and payments and such, I would recommmend doing all of your calculations in "month" and then when you have the total in months convert that to years if needed/desired.